# Poisson Distribution of a radioactive decay

Tags: probability, self-study, poisson-distribution, mean

You have received a radioactive mass that is claimed to have a mean decay rate of at least 1 particle per second. If the mean decay rate is less than 1 per second, you may return the product for a refund. Let X be the number of decay events counted in 10 seconds.

Part a. If the mean decay rate is exactly 1 per second, what is P(X <= 8)?

I got 0.33282.

Part b. Based on the answer to part a, if the mean decay rate is 1 particle per second, would eight events in 10 seconds be an unusually small number?

I'm a little confused on part b because isn't it really obvious that yeah we should return it because the mean for particles per second is 8/10 =0.8 when it should equal 1.0?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: No, it's not obvious at all. If I toss a coin ten times and only get 4 heads, should I conclude that my coin is biased toward tails?

Comment: If X is the number of decay events for 10 seconds and I only get 8 decaying events in 10 seconds that is less than the 10 making the avg of 1 decay per second untrue. Therefore I should return the product. Is that the correct thinking? I guess I'm not really sure what it is asking.